# How to hook windows7 explorer.exe to hide file

Tags: c++, windows

I want to hook `explorer.exe` on windows 7 to hide files,I have tried to find out which API it uses by `windbg breakpoint` and import table,but didn't have any result.Then I search for which API it uses on the Internet,then i have found  `IShellFolder::EnumObjects`,but i don't know what can i do next

Comment: FindFrstFile/FindNextFile is used.

Answer (score 0):

You mean [SetFileAttributes](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileattributesw)?

e.g:

`SetFileAttributes(L"c:\\path\\filename.txt", FILE_ATTRIBUTE_HIDDEN);`

Comment: no,I mean how to hide file by hooking the api which is used by explorer.exe in Windows 7 to list files,I'm sorry,my statement is terrible